# Python Sublime Text output window show/hide

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm running the Python code in Sublime - it works fine.

The only quirk I noticed is that when the code is executing if I, for example, do a search in the code the output window disappears and I haven't found a way to bring it back.

How to show/hide the python output window?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To show the build results panel, select **`Tools -> Build Results -> Show Build Results`**. There are also options in that menu to move back and forth in the build results history.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a plugin for the interpreter. For example REPL - https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL .